# Splitting a string in Java into an array from the input received from Android Studio with .split("")

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, android-studio-3.0

Java and Android Studio newbie trying my hands on my first project and I have a question. I have a string called 'key' which I am receiving as an input from the user (from Android Studio emulator). I want to break this key string into independent letters. So, I did

```
String[] keys = key.split("");
```

This worked fine when I was setting the key manually, but when I receive it as an input from the emulator, it adds an extra empty string in the array. So, for example, if I am manually setting key to "abcD":

```
key = "abcD";
String[] keys = key.split(""); // keys = {"a", "b", "c", "D"}
```

which is great, just how it should be. But when I make this key dynamic and accept it from the emulator; let's say I type the same key in the emulator:

```
String[] keys = key.split(""); // keys = {"", "a", "b", "c", "D"}
```

is what is being set in keys.

Why is this happening and how can I get rid of this? I could just assume that this is how it going to be and probably just start my index on keys from 1 instead of 0; but I would still like to understand why is it adding the extra "", only if I receive this key from the emulator?

Thank you!

Comment: I'd use `key.trim()` to get rid of spaces etc in the beginning and the end of the string. Does `key.trim().split("")` give you the desired result?

Comment: How do you read the input?

Comment: @MuratK. I am reading the input as:  key = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.key);

Comment: @Stefan No, I still get {"", "a", "b", "c", "D"} after using key.trim().split("")

Answer (score 0):

What you have should work. If, however, the spaces provided are defaulting to... something else? You can use the whitespace regex:

```
str = "Hello I'm your String";
String[] splited = str.split("\\s+");
```

This will cause any number of consecutive spaces to split your string into tokens.

Comment: But I do not want to split a sentence based on spaces; I want to split each word into letters. I have checks in place that disallow the user to enter anything but alphabets. I tried your version, but that just returns {"abcD"} back, which is fine because we are checking for the spaces. Any comments on why is that extra ""  being added to the array for dynamic inputs?

Answer (score 0):

I get the same "error" (empty string at pos 0) when I run your first example:

```
key = "abcD";
String[] keys = key.split(""); // keys = {"", "a", "b", "c", "D"}
```

So I suggest you use String.charAt():

```
for (int i = 0; i < key.length(); i++) {
    System.out.println(key.charAt(i));
}
```

That works for me.